# Parsing json with php and return object

Tags: php, json, parsing

I just need to parse a JSON :

```
object(stdClass)#363 (3) 

    { 
        ["type"]=> string(8) "champion" 
        ["version"]=> string(6) "5.22.3" 
        ["data"]=> object(stdClass)#362 (127) { 
            ["Thresh"]=> object(stdClass)#366 (4) { ["id"]=> int(412) ["key"]=> string(6) "Thresh" ["name"]=> string(6) "Thresh" ["title"]=> string(18) "Garde aux chaÃ®nes" } 
            ["Aatrox"]=> object(stdClass)#365 (4) { ["id"]=> int(266) ["key"]=> string(6) "Aatrox" ["name"]=> string(6) "Aatrox" ["title"]=> string(17) "Ã‰pÃ©e des Darkin" } 
            ["Tryndamere"]=> object(stdClass)#368 (4) { ["id"]=> int(23) ["key"]=> string(10) "Tryndamere" ["name"]=> string(10) "Tryndamere" ["title"]=> string(11) "Roi barbare" } etc...
```

How to parse all the datas from this JSON with PHP by using object return.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: I have no idea what are you asking about. Please provide an example input (JSON as I understand), the code, that you've already tried, and the current and expected outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use json_decode.

Returns as object:

```
json_decode($json_string);
```

Returns as associative array:

```
json_decode($json_string, true);
```

Comment: Where do you see any JSON string in OP's question?

Answer (score 0):

From what I guess you used json_decode and it returned object. You can now access object values using variable name let's say $var

```
echo $var->type; // will output champion
```

You can also convert json to array by providing second argument set to `true`

then you can access this data via

```
 echo $var['type'];
```